# Commands to get SVN Log Output in a Copy,Pastable Format

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I need to send a list of changed files with extra notes from commits I've done over the past week.

I'm looking for a way to get SVN log output in a format I could paste into an email.  I use VisualSVN and Tortoise SVN but I don't see a way to copy the log outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i cant do this via a command - but if you are in the Tortoise svn log then select a reange of revision and then right click and "copy to clip board" and it will give you the following format:

Revision: xxxxxx
Author: user
Date: 11:19:21, 05 October 2010
Message:

---

hope it helps

paul

Comment: i know its not ideal but its fine if you dont have command line access to the SVN server

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to use the svn command line client. You can find it [here](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/)

See also [the "svn log" command.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

Comment: `svn log xxxx | clip` puts it directly on the windows clipboard